# How to export a function in bash over ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, function

I would like to write a function in bash, then export that function and execute it over ssh. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfunc() {
    echo $1
}        
export -f myfunc
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain it more? Are you trying to execute the function via calling the script remotely?

Comment: I want to use the script in GNU parallel. I saw a solution on http://superuser.com/questions/620782/exporting-bash-functions-through-ssh but I don't seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example that you mention in your comment it is `parallel` that transfers the function to the remote environment (and it works only bash). So you have to use parallel to try it. After defining and exporting (as per Q), you should:

```
function myfunc() {
    echo $1
}        
export -f myfunc
parallel --env myfunc -S server 'myfunc abc' ::: bar
```

There is a part in the [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Transferring-environment-variables-and-functions) about that.

The bash function forwarding feature with --env has been available starting with `parallel` version 20130722.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that doesn't work for me when I try it in bash. I each time get "bash: line 2: command not found".

Comment: You should update your question with what you actually type into bash, and not a half finished script which doesn't show what you do with parallel. (as without parallel it will not work).

Comment: I update the answer with the full 5 lines that work if cut-and-pasted into bash. The only thing you need to change is the "server" to your servername (or login@servername)

Comment: If I try your suggested code, I still get
> bash: line 2: myfunc: command not found

Comment: Can you include the os and version you running. And output from `echo $BASH_VERSION` of the shell you pasted the commands into?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with version 20121122 of GNU parallel and version 4.2.25(1)-release of bash.

Comment: If you look in the NEWS file in the gnu-parallel distribution you can read that the --env can transfer bash functions starting with parallel 20130722. You need to upgrade!

Comment: These days have a look at `man env_parallel`.

Comment: Error in bash line 2 smells like DOS Carriage Return. Check this `od -t x1 myscript | grep 0d` - is there any lines with `0d`? Then remove them with `tr -d '\r' < myscript > myscript2`

Answer (score 1):

You may use something similar to this,

file myfunc.sh

```
function myfunc() {
    echo $1
}
```

Then source the function within your shell like,

```
source myfunc.sh
```

Then you may execute the "myfunc" on the remote node like so,

```
ssh user@ip "$(declare -f myfunc; myfunc 'cmdlinearg' )"
```

where "cmdlinearg" is the value of 1st command line variable that shall be echoed within the function.

Ref url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqHjc7hlqd0    towards the end

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it works for all cases, it's kind of naughty:

```
function remote-function() {
   local param1=$1
   echo $param1
}
ssh_connection=someone@somewhere
echo $(type remote-cleanup | tail -n+2 | sed 's#^}#; }#g')'; remote-function hello '  | ssh ${ssh_connection} bash
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your environment is not huge:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="This is my var: "
alias myecho=echo

function myfunc() {
    myecho $myvar $1
}        

env_parallel -S server myfunc ::: a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example (at least using GNU bash, version 5.2.2(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)):

```
#!/bin/bash

# time comparison between local time and time on remote server
# specify the remote server as parameter 1

# expect to see something similar to this, when using remote as $1:
# time @ remote -------------: Wed Apr 26 11:32:14 CEST 2023 remote
# time @ local --------------: Wed Apr 26 11:32:14 CEST 2023 computer

myhostname=$1

# create a padded version of our hostname
# this allows to compare both dates more easily by looking at it
# based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409399/padding-characters-in-printf
m=$(echo -n "${myhostname} $(printf '\055%.0s' {1..40})" | head -c 20)
l=$(echo -n "local $(printf '\055%.0s' {1..40})" | head -c 20)

function dateit {
  # add hostname to output to make sure we have the correct time
  # add LC_ALL=C to get a uniform date output
  echo "$(LC_ALL=C date) ${HOSTNAME}"
}

# Note that, unescaped, this -- i.e. $(declare -f dateit) -- expands on the client side.
# and that is what we want, therefore we disable this shellcheck here
# shellcheck disable=SC2029
echo -en "time @ ${m}: $(ssh "${myhostname}" "$(declare -f dateit); dateit" )\ntime @ ${l}: $(dateit)\n"
```