# using export inside the SSH and using the value globally within the script

Tags: linux, ssh, ksh

When I run the below command:

```
ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -T <server> <<'EOF'
export INTIAL_COUNT=$(ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep "/bin/ksh /test/bin/worker.sh" |wc -l)
EOF

echo ${INTIAL_COUNT}
```

output I get is null

expected output is some value

```
echo ${INTIAL_COUNT}
10
```

Comment: Are you executing `echo ${INITIAL_COUNT}` on the local system or remote system?

Comment: local server after the EOF part is complete.

Comment: Why would a variable you exported on a remote machine be available locally?  It also wont be available remotely outside of our ssh session though.  In order to make an environmental variable permanent you need to add it to your profile on the machine you want that variable on.

Comment: The value is assigned to `INITIAL_COUNT` in the shell started by `ssh` and will not be carried over to the local shell. To set the variable locally, use `INITIAL_COUNT=$( ssh ... )`. Also consider using `pgrep`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a function in bash over ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103393/how-to-export-a-function-in-bash-over-ssh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
INTIAL_COUNT=$(ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -T <server> <<'EOF'
ps -ef|grep -c "/bin/ksh /test/bin/[w]orker.sh" 
EOF
)
```

where

- `grep -v grep` is replaced by `grep [w]` whitch not match itself
- `grep  ... | wc -l` is replaced by `grep -c`
- `$( .. )` construct can span line

or

```
INTIAL_COUNT=$(ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -T <server> 'ps -ef|grep -c "/bin/ksh /test/bin/[w]orker.sh"')
```

even shorter.